# Hover wont work in html and css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Hover function will not work in css and html.

I have a navigation menu across the top and i would like a drop down menu off one of the menu icons. I have positioned everything correctly however the hover just wont work.

My code is as follows:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #151515;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #EFF5F8;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  width: 860px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#slideshow {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  clear: left;
  width: 860px;
  height: 470px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: #3399CC;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: source-sans-pro;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#main {
  width: 58%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  float: left;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 34%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  float: left;
}
footer {
  clear: left;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  background-color: #43A6CB;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
figure {
  width: 420px;
}
figure img {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #999999;
}
figcaption {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.centered {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.floatleft {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.floatright {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
  color: #FF6600;
}
a:visited {
  color: #FF944C;
}
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: #7F3300;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#mainnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainnav a {
  width: 20%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
#mainnav a:hover,
#mainnav a:active,
#mainnav a:focus,
#mainnav a.thispage {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #43A6CB;
}
article,
aside,
figure,
footer,
header,
nav {
  display: block;
}
ol {
  font-weight: 600;
  fobt-size: 25px;
  color: red;
}
#dropdown1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 208px;
  left: 345px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#dropdown1 > li {
  width: 861px;
  float: left;
}
.review:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Movie Night Reviews</title>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="top">
      <h1>Movie Night Reviews</h1>
      <nav id="mainnav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="thispage">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="trailers.html">Trailers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="review"><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
            <ul id="dropdown1">
              <li><a href="civil_war.html">Civil War</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="furious_7.html">Furious 7</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="fantastic_four.html">Fantastic Four</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="jurassic_world.html">Jurassic World</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="agents_of_shield.html">Agents of Shield</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="slideshow">
      <div id="comslider_in_point_720546"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var oCOMScript720546 = document.createElement('script');
        oCOMScript720546.src = "comslider720546/comsliderd.js?timestamp=1437916662";
        oCOMScript720546.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(oCOMScript720546);
      </script>
    </div>
    <article id="main">
      <h2>Top 10 Highest Grossing Movies</h2>
      <p>The following list is of the highest grossing movies ever made. Director James Cameron currently holds the top two spots after directing both Avartar and Titanic.</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Avatar</li>
        <li>Titanic</li>
        <li>Juassic World</li>
        <li>The Avengers</li>
        <li>Furious 7</li>
        <li>Avengers: Age of Ultron</li>
        <li>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2</li>
        <li>Frozen</li>
        <li>Iron Man 3</li>
        <li>Transformers: Dark of the Moon</li>
      </ol>
      <figure class="centered">
        <img src="Images/titanic.jpg" width="400" height="266" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Titanic, the oldest film in the top 10 still sits in a comfy second place just below Avatar. Both directed by world-renowned director James Cameron.</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <h2>Top 10 Highest Grossing Movie Franchises</h2>
      <p>The following list is of the Top 10 Highest Grossing Movie Franchises of all time. The Marvel Cinematic Universe franchise currently sits at the top nearly a billion higher than Harry Potter and roughly 2.5 billion higher than James Bond which is
        the closest franchise that is also still running.</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Marvel Cinematic Universe</li>
        <li>Harry Potter</li>
        <li>James Bond</li>
        <li>Middle-Earth</li>
        <li>Star Wars</li>
        <li>Spider-Man</li>
        <li>The Fast and the Furious</li>
        <li>Batman</li>
        <li>Transformers</li>
        <li>Pirates of the Caribbean</li>
      </ol>
      <figure class="centered">
        <img src="Images/antman.jpg" width="400" height="266" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Ant-Man, the latest film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe franchise looks set to push them even further ahead than the rest of the Top 10.</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </article>
    <aside id="sidebar">
      <h2>Tweets by IMDb</h2>
      <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/IMDb" data-widget-id="625318734555693056">Tweets by @IMDb</a>
      <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
          if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
      </script>
    </aside>
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Copyright 2013 Bayside Beat</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The big white gap is an image slideshow not just a massive gap.

If anyone an help me get this working it would be appreciated.

Comment: replace `#dropdown1` with `.review ul` in `css`

Comment: See my answer for detailed change to your css and fiddle. please mark correct if this solves your initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your code to make it work.

you need to use .review > a:hover + #dropdown1 to change the visibility.

```
#dropdown1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 208px;
  left: 345px;
  z-index: 10;
}
#dropdown1:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
#dropdown1 > li {
  width: 861px;
  float: left;
}
.review > a:hover + #dropdown1 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

problem is your menu is too far away to stay visible when you leave .review. you need to bring the menu up closer or use a thick white border at the top so it still looks spaced how you have it

https://jsfiddle.net/gL54eevn/3/

Comment: Yes that worked thanks! All i needed to do then was set the .review class to position relative ad then i could position absolute the dropdown menu without it ruining the layout.